# Rails set polymorphic id on saving parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a person object in my application but within the controller when `@person.save!` is called the exception `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Contacts contactable can't be blank` is thrown. This is due to the `contactable_id` not being set.

I know that I can save the person and then create and save a contact, but would preder to save all in one hit. What am I missing?

The classes involved are below:

**person.rb**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :contacts, as: :contactable

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts
end
```

**contact.rb**

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :contactable, polymorphic: true

end
```

The form posts the following:

```
{"commit"=>"Add Person",
 "person"=>{"name"=>"Fred Bloggs"},
 "website"=>"http://www.example.com",
 "controller"=>"person",
 "action"=>"create"}
```

and is processed in the controller create method.

**person_controller.rb**

```
class PersonController < ApplicationController
    def create

        load = person_params.merge({contacts_attributes: [{address:params[:website],contact_type:"web", contact_sub_type: "main"}]})
        @person = Person.new(load)
        @person.save!
    end

        private
        def person_params
          params.require(:person).permit( ..... contacts_attributes: [:address, :contact_type, :contact_sub_type])
        end
end
```

Comment: That's the complete model code?  There are no validations there at all.

Comment: Thanks @smathy you are correct. I included validations for the contactable_id and contactable_type when testing. I guess that they are not needed as they are essentially internal to the polymorphic processing. Removing them allows the contact and person objects to be saved.